# Does google search have the ability to do a 'notinurl' search?

Tags: search

I'm trying to find all the pages in my site that are indexed by google so I've searched for `site:mysite.com` .  My product page show up in loads of these results so I'm trying to exclude them from the results, something like `site:mysite.com notinurl:product` but I can't seem to find anything that works, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using minus sign before your term:

```
site:mysite.com -product
```

This should exclude all results that contain your product - be aware, it's not just the url.